# How to Fetch an Individual ID from an multiple documents in Firestore Collection, reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have documents in my firestore, currently what I want to achieve is when I want to view a particular document it should auto target the ID in that document. Here's my code snippet:-

```js
 const collectionRef = collection(db, "mcsSystems/" + userId , "reportmcs")

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    const getTasks = async () => {
      const q = query(collectionRef)
      await getDocs(q).then((task)=>{
       let tasksData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id}))
      setTasks(tasksData)
      setFetch(tasksData.map(task => task.id))
      console.log("fetchData", tasksData)
      console.log("taskData", tasksData)
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
    getTasks()
  }, [])

  let cultureId = fetch
```

From the code snippet above, I set a state(fetch) to get the ID whenever I view the document. Currently I'm mapping through all documents and when I click to view it shows all the ID from the documents in that collection.. Here's my console log
[image]

What I want to achieve is when I view a particular document, it should return only the individual ID not all the ID in that collection..

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "view a particular document". How does that action inform how this code runs? You have a query that returns a bunch of documents, but you haven't said how you know ahead of time which document you're looking for.  If you already know which document you want and have its ID, then there is no need to query for all of them, just use `getDoc` to get the one you want.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson If I wanted to view the first document, I would have done this, setFetch(tasksData[0].id), but I might have lots of document in that collection, I want to target the particular ID without having to set an index because I might have more than one document

Comment: I'm also not sure I follow. If you know the ID of the document you want to read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document. If you don't know the ID, but want to limit the query to reading a single document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data